# Is there anyway to derive a new stream that doesn't check the test method every time?

Tags: dart

I am looking for a way to derive new Streams from a broadcast stream based on a test method but that will not cause the test method to be called for every subscription:

> Stream where(Function bool test(T event))
>
> Creates a new stream from this stream that discards some data events.
>
> The new stream sends the same error and done events as this stream, but it only sends the data events that satisfy the test.
>
> The returned stream is a broadcast stream if this stream is. If a broadcast stream is listened to more than once, each subscription will
>   individually perform the test.

are there any other ways to derive sub broadcast streams from a source broadcast stream that will not call the test method for every subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a simple solution within the core async API but I have found that if you forward the stream on to another stream for each type of test the performance savings are huge, [this](https://github.com/0xor1/streamers/blob/dev/lib/emitter.dart) is my class that uses this stream forwarding technique it performs vastly better than the second original version beneath that will enforce the type check on every subscription for every emitted object:

```dart
/// A mixin class to enable any class to act as a generic emitter of objects.
class Emitter {

  final StreamController _controller = new StreamController.broadcast();
  final Map<Type, Stream> _streamCache = new Map<Type, Stream>();

  /**
  * Emit an object.
  *
  *     emit(new Foo());
  *
  * Will send the new Foo object down the stream returned by `on(Foo)`.
  */
  void emit(obj) => _controller.add(obj);

  /// Get the stream of [type].
  Stream on(Type type){
    var stream = _streamCache[type];
    if(stream == null){
      StreamController controller = new StreamController.broadcast();
      _streamCache[type] = stream = type == All? _controller.stream: controller.stream;
      if(type != All){
        _controller.stream.where(_typeMatcher(type)).listen(controller.add, onError: controller.addError, onDone: controller.close);
      }
    }
    return stream;
  }
}
```

And this is the old very slow implementation of the on method:

```dart
  /// Get the stream of [type].
  Stream on(Type type) => type == All? _controller.stream:  _controller.stream.where(_typeMatcher(type));
```

For some performance numbers, if you emit 100000 objects to 200 listeners the high performance runs in 6.6 seconds and the slow version runs in 20.2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Quiver's `StreamRouter` might not be exactly what you want, but it does perform the test only once-per-event, not once-per-event-per-subsriber. It's somewhat similar to your `Emitter`, except that events can only flow into one derived stream.

```dart
var router = new StreamRouter(new Stream.fromIterable(range(0, 10)));
var odds = router.route((i) => i % 2 == 1);
odds.listen((i) { print(i); });
odds.listen((i) { print("$i is odd"); });
```

The predicate passed to `route` is only call once per event.

Here's the docs:

http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/quiver/0.19.0-dev.3/index.html#quiver/quiver-async.StreamRouter

Also, not that your `Emmiter` doesn't need to cache the Streams to get the behavior that the test is only called once, that comes from manually creating a controller and calling `add()`. So you could get the same thing with:

```dart
/// Get the stream of [type].
Stream on(Stream source, Type type) {
  var controller = new StreamController();
  controller.addStream(source.where(_typeMatcher(type)));
  return controller.stream;
}
```

Comment: The caching is required as if you don't store the new controllers stream then calling emitter.on(type) over and over will keep creating new streams and enforcing the predicate test method per event per subscription again. Thanks for the quiver tut its certainly something to consider.

Comment: The caching keeps multiple calls to `on(type)` from causing multiple test invocations, but without caching if you call `on(source, type)` once, then call `listen()` on the result multiple times, you don't get multiple tests per subscriber. So it's a question of multiple `listen()` calls, or multiple `on(type)` calls. One thing about caching is that you need tests that can be properly cached, this won't always be the case with closures, though it will with `Type`.